# .Net MAUI: Different result for CollectionView/DataTemplate between Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, .net, maui

I wrote a simple CollectionView (.Net MAUI) with a DataTemplate and get completely different results when I deploy the code to either a Android device or a iOS device.

It would be really awesome if someone has a hint - this project drives me crazy since 4 months :D

I used the same code in Xamarin before without any issues.

**EDIT**:
I added the WidthRequest (and a margin) and now the style is as expected - thanks so far. (I also checked the text colors which are fine and I changed the TextColor of two lables to red - just for testing)

But I still have another issue. When the iOS App is opened, the part on the right hand side does not show up and it seems that the app is hung up. If I try to scroll, then I get a completlely random list of my items (some are missing) and everything is stuck.

```
<RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Cryptocurrency">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Source="{Binding image}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" Margin="0,0,10,0" />

                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16" />
                        <Label Text="Price" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Padding="0,0,20,0"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16" />
                        <Label Text="x to ATH" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16" />

                        <Label Text="{Binding market_cap_rank}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="13" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding current_price, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Padding="0,0,20,0"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="13" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding RatioToATH}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="13" />
                        
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"      
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
```

[image][image][image]

**EDIT2**:
It also works flawlessly on macOS (MacCatalyst)

[image]

Comment: First, don't assume any default colors. Specify all text colors and background colors using `Style`s. (Both Xamarin and Maui use native controls, and each platform has its own native defaults. I'm surprised it worked on Xamarin; maybe had styles set in app? Or some theme?) Then, seems to be an indenting problem. But easier to see once the colors all show up.

Comment: I generated the same code test as yours and it is normal. What needs to be said is that I did not use `Style`. You said: "and everything is stuck", is it impossible to scroll? If so you can try the answer in [MAUI - CollectionView and scrolling - not working with IOS emulators.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1147759/maui-collectionview-and-scrolling-not-working-with)

Comment: Thanks @DongzhiWang-MSFT but unfortunately it didn't work. Maybe because I don't use a ScrollViewer. I also tried to change the code to my RefreshView but this one does not have the necessary methods. One other reason could be, that the Programm didn't accepted my code, I also tried the following approach but my breakpoint in the new FixedScrollViewHandler class was never reached

Comment: Does the CollectionView display normally after you try to remove the RefreshView?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT: yes it does, I'll add a screenshot later. The scroll function is also working now, so I just have to care about a refresh function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the RefreshView due to a known and fixed but not deployed error in maui so far. See issue [#9209](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9209#issuecomment-1304614755) on Github (Thanks @Dongzhi Wang-MSFT)

Everything is then working except the reload function. In my case I wanted to reload only on application start and on resume (so basically every time when it is used). For that I have a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75529552/refresh-list-via-onresume-event-in-net-maui/75530032#75530032) (Thanks @ewerspej)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could set the constraint of Image(give it a width), please refer to the following code.

```
<Image Source="{Binding image}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="150" />
```

Comment: Thanks, the WidthRequest improved the style a lot, but the app still has weird behaviour. I edited the top post

Answer (score -1):

Yes! this is how MAUI work they will call out the native controls instead of control that is written in the middle layer like Flutter
They provide you OnPlatform so you can easily adjust the UI better

```
IsVisible={x:OnPlatform WinUI=true, Android=false, iOS=false, Tizen=false, MacCatalyst=false}
```

Comment: Read the question details. You've answered the question "How do I ask for different results on ios and Android". THIS question is "I want same results on both, but they are different - how fix so same?"

Comment: Can you change the Textcolor to White ? I think they are match with the background color

Comment: At the Image element inside your datatemplate, please give it the width 150 and reprovide the results

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I changed the width of the image, which helped a lot but the text color is not the issue - I also changed it for a test which doesn't fixed the issue because the app seems to be stuck