# Refresh list via OnResume event in .NET MAUI

Tags: ios, .net, mvvm, refresh, maui

Regarding to a known .NET MAUI error in ScrollViewer & RefreshView, which is discussed about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419309/net-maui-different-result-for-collectionview-datatemplate-between-android-and?noredirect=1), I am trying to find a workaround.

So I removed my RefreshView and now using just a CollectionView. The only function that is missing now is the "refresh-function" of my list, which I want to trigger now with the OnResume event in the App.xaml.cs which looks like that now:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DependencyService.Register<Services.MockDataStore>();
        MainPage = new AppShell();      
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        // method call should be implemented here
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to access a method from my view model from that line of code?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You could use WeakReferenceManager for that, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956261/4308455)

Comment: BTW, MAUI uses the builder pattern and comes with dependency injection built-in (in case you're using Shell, which seems to be the case here). There's no need for the DependencyService.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `WeakReferenceManager` for this.

First, you define a class that serves as a type for the message:

```cs
public class ResumeMessage {}
```

Then, in your ViewModel or View *(depending on where and how you would refresh the `CollectionView`)*, you could subscribe to the `ResumeMessage` like this:

```cs
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ResumeMessage>(this, (sender, args) =>
{
    // here you can refresh the CollectionView
});
```

And in the `OnResume()` method of your `App` class, you can send the message that informs all subscribers that something should happen based on the `ResumeMessage`:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DependencyService.Register<Services.MockDataStore>();
        MainPage = new AppShell();      
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new ResumeMessage());
    }
}
```